# Positioning trouble

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm having some issues with putting a some content with putting some content below my hero / jumbotron image. **The underline stuff is not important! It is animtated on load with some jquery.** Code Below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weqj1ax3/)

**I want to "What we do" content below the jumbotron image**

HTML:

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-text">
        <h1 class="invis-selection">Header Text</h1>
        <div id="underline-1"></div>
        <div id="underline-2"></div>
        <div id="underline-3"></div>
        <div id="underline-4"></div>
    </div>
    <img class="hero-img" src="img/city-night.png" alt="Hero Image" />
</div>

<div class="wwd-main">
    <h1>What we do</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 125px;  
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.hero-text h1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 125px;  
    font-size: 7.1em;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.hero-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wwd-main {
    position: relative;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem, however as your screen gets vertically smaller you will notice the text at the bottom slowly disappearing. This is because you are using %'s to define the dimensions of the elements, as the screen shrinks the box will be smaller relative to your screen size. To solve this, change the 10% I used for .wwd-main to 90px.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.hero{
    position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.hero-text {
 position: absolute;
 width: 640px;
 height: 125px; 
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.hero-text h1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
 height: 125px; 
 font-size: 7.1em;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.hero-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wwd-main {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 class="invis-selection">Header Text</h1>
  </div>
 <img class="hero-img" src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Shanghai-City-Night-1920x1080.jpg" alt="Hero Image" />
</div>
    
<div class="wwd-main">
  <h1>What we do</h1>
</div>
```

edit: What I did to solve the issue was change .wwd-main from `position:relative;` to `position:fixed;` and added `bottom:0;` This ensures the text will always be fixed to the bottom of your screen with a 0px offset.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `position: fixed;` from `.hero`.
And add this to your CSS, to collapse the margins:

```
.wwd-main > h1
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That work. Kinda, Its now not a full jumbotron image now. There is about 15px of white space at the bottom of the jumbotron

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the Height and Width of the text twice.
Here is the changed version of the code.
You can now customize your styling to make it look the way you want.

PS: I would recommend you to use Bootstrap or any other libraries.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.hero{
   
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.hero-text {
 position: fixed;
 width: 640px;
 height: 125px; 
 top: 20%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.hero-text h1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
 height: 125px; 
 font-size: 7.1em;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.hero-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wwd-main {
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 class="invis-selection">Header Text</h1>
  </div>
 <img class="hero-img" src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Shanghai-City-Night-1920x1080.jpg" alt="Hero Image" />
</div>
    
<div class="wwd-main">
  <h1>What we do</h1>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/j2g6tk2f/)